# Who is this character in a green shirt swinging a flagpole?

Tags: durarara

I found this image today, and am curious as to who the character therein is.

[image: The unknown mystery character of DOOM]

The only English result produced by a reverse image search is [this blog post](http://ikebukuroconfessions.tumblr.com/post/18339149773/i-hate-durarara-ocs) which suggests that the origin is the anime *Durarara!!*. However, I've been looking at various *Durarara!!* character profiles, such as [the category on their Wikia](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters) and [this image of all the major characters](http://japanime4eva.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/durarara-characters1.jpg), and this boy does not appear to be in them.

All this leads me to believe this shot might be a flashback or something (as he looks quite a bit younger), or perhaps another anime if I've been misled...

What is the name of this character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually just **HEIWAJIMA Shizuo** when he was younger. There's a flashback in episode 7, lasting from roughly 06:48 to 11:12, that shows how Shizuo got to be so strong in the first place. Your screencap occurs around 07:55.

Comment: Geez, he sure has changed appearance in so many years...